# What is the significance of Trinath Mela, where the three supreme gods are worshipped?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahma, puja, vrata

Villagers in Odisha many times perform Trinath Mela at their own house, where all the three supreme gods Brahma, Vishnu and Maheswara altogether are worshipped at the same time. This Pooja is said as Trinath Mela.

[image]

What is the significance of this Pooja? Is there any story?